# Property of $\frac{\int_t^\infty x f(x) dx}{\int_t^\infty f(x) dx}$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

$f(x)$ is a probability density function over $(0, \infty)$.

Is there any studies on the following function of $t$?

$$g(t)=\frac{\int_t^\infty x f(x) dx}{\int_t^\infty  f(x) dx}$$

Thanks.

Comment: So essentially $g(t)=\frac{E(X)-\int_0^t x f(x) dx}{1-F(t)}$

Comment: That is ture. Thanks. I also found that it is the expectation of $X$ on condition that $X>t$.

Comment: Yep, that's correct :) I wonder what it could represent...

Comment: Probably worth adding the *reference-request* tag?